# how to add inline jquery event

Tags: jquery, events, inline

I want to add jQuery event like `mouseenter` in this way like

```
ImageTag mouseenter="callSomefunction" id="imgId"
```

instead of

```
ImageTag onmouseover="callSomefunction" id="imgId"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Would you give us some reason, for this kind of approach?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does not work on the tag as a property.

You need to find the element with javascript, so in a javascript block you will find the element then you will be able to bind an event:

```
<script>
    $("#imgId").mouseenter(function() { /* your stuff */ });
</script>
```

This script block must execute after the element, because the element has to exist before you try to get it.

You should read more about jQuery before trying anything, http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stops you to add whathever you want in your markup, however:

1. That would yield non-valid markup.
2. It will have no effect, as mouseenter is not a valid attribute for a tag.

To answer your question:

```
<img id="imgId" mouseenter="callSomefunction" />
```

I don't recommend this approach though.